# How do I connect to an Energy Efficient Ethernet enabled switch?

Tags: ethernet

Is Ubuntu ready for [Energy Efficient Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet)?

I tried to connect to a 1Gbit EEE switch but it failed, syslog says:

```
NetworkManager[1041]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed')
```

I succesfully connected to 100MBit and 1GBit switches without EEE.

If I force it to use 100MBit:

```
sudo mii-tool -F 100baseTx-FD
```

it works.

Here is the output of `sudo mii-tool -v -v`:

for connection with **100Mbit switch**:

```
Using SIOCGMIIPHY=0x8947
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
  registers for MII PHY 1: 
    1140 796d 006e 3211 0de1 45e1 0007 2001
    0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 3000
    0000 6c40 0000 5c50 0080 0000 0000 0000
    2d00 4177 1000 0004 0000 0000 0030 e088
  product info: vendor 00:1b:8c, model 33 rev 1
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

for connection with **a regular 1Gbit switch**:

```
Using SIOCGMIIPHY=0x8947
eth0: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
  registers for MII PHY 1: 
    1140 796d 006e 3211 0de1 c5e1 000f 2001
    4d07 0300 3800 0000 0000 0000 0000 3000
    0000 ac40 0000 5c18 0001 0000 0000 3633
    2d00 4177 1000 0004 0000 0000 0030 e088
  product info: vendor 00:1b:8c, model 33 rev 1
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

for connection with **1Gbit EEE switch**:

```
Using SIOCGMIIPHY=0x8947
eth0: no link
  registers for MII PHY 1: 
    1140 7949 006e 3211 0de1 cde1 000d 2001
    0000 0300 0c00 0000 0000 0000 0000 3000
    0000 2000 0000 3850 0000 0000 0000 0000
    2d00 4177 1000 0004 0000 0000 0030 e088
  product info: vendor 00:1b:8c, model 33 rev 1
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: no link
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

Here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"`:

```
04:00.5 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:5130]
    Kernel driver in use: jme
    Kernel modules: jme
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0083]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1305]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux user-B5130M 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: My thoughts are that this is very much hardware specific. What exact ethernet card do you have? Please include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"` and `uname -a`. Also, did you try another operating system? Another (shorter) cable? Do other PCs have the same issue? etc. I have a few Green Gigabit Ethernet switches (personal and in the company I worked for) and I've never seen such issues.

Comment: i did try other cables (5m long) as i first thougt the cable is faulty.

Comment: Okay, found it. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, Ubuntu is perfectly capable of that.

However, this depends on the driver (kernel module) and hardware support for your network interface card. It seems that you're looking at a ...

#### JMicron hardware bug

According to the [FreeBSD documentation of the JMicron ethernet driver](http://howtounix.info/man/FreeBSD/man4/jme.4):

> If the full mask revision number of JMC25x controller is less than or equal to 4 and link partner enabled IEEE 802.3az Energy Efficient Ethernet feature, the controller would not be able to establish a 1000baseT link. Also if the length of cable is longer than 120 meters, controller can not establish a 1000baseT link. The known workaround for the issue is to force manual link configuration with 100baseTX instead of relying on auto-negotiation.

Since you have `rev 03`, you're very much likely running into this issue. So I guess it's time to replace your network interface card or to live with 100Mbit. :)

In case this is a new machine (notebook?), I suggest to send it back to the shop for warranty and get the NIC replaced. Newer revisions of the hardware are fixed, apparently.

Comment: Thank you so much! Im going to live with it since i have the notebook for more than two years, maybe im going to swap the switch with one without EEE since i already have one in use.